# Qiskit "statevector_gpu" method not available

Tags: qiskit, programming, simulation

I am trying to use the `statevector_gpu` simulation method in Qiskit Aer (see [this](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.StatevectorSimulator.html) page). I installed `qiskit-aer-gpu` according to the instructions on [this](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer) page. It was working last week and then stopped working. I'm not sure what changed. (It's a shared computer.) I get the error message `qiskit.providers.aer.aererror.AerError: "Invalid simulation method statevector_gpu. Available methods are: ['automatic', 'statevector']"`.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is the relevant system information:

- It is a shared computer running `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`.
- I have `qiskit 0.23.0`, `qiskit-aer 0.7.0`, `qiskit-aer-gpu 0.7.0` installed in an environment in `conda 4.8.5` with `python 3.8.5`.
- `nvcc --version` gives `Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130`
- `nvidia-smi` shows 4 GPUs available and indicates `CUDA Version: 10.2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `qiskit-aer` and `qiskit-aer-gpu` are mutually exclusive packages. They contain the same code except that the `qiskit-aer-gpu` package built with CUDA support enabled. If you install both packages at the same time the contents of the 2 packages will interfere with each other. I would recommend creating a new conda environment and installing `qiskit-terra` and `qiskit-aer-gpu` manually with `pip install -U qiskit-terra qiskit-aer-gpu` (and add `qiskit-ignis`, `qiskit-aqua`, and `qiskit-ibmq-provider` if they're needed). If you still have issues with only qiskit-aer-gpu installed in the environment please file an issue at https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/issues and we can work on debugging it there.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!!