# How can we access GPU to execute qiskit codes. If possible give me a sample code

Tags: qiskit

I'm practicing with qiskit experiments. Try to work it with GPU installed in my system. But it takes 100% performance of CPU and didn't consider the GPU.

Kindly help me to run the qiskit codes with GPU.

Thanks..

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you want to do? Are you trying to simulate quantum circuits with more than 30 qubits?

Comment: Related question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67480117/how-to-use-qiskit-gpu-on-window

Comment: Hi, were you able to execute and if yes, what specs your GPU supports? As I am using Cuda 12.1 and GPU with CC 5.2 but I am getting error `cudaErrorNoKernelImageForDevice`

Answer (score 4):

According to [qiskit-aer README](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer#installing-gpu-support), you can install `qiskit-aer-gpu` to utilize GPU for simulation. This package requires CUDA® 10.1 or newer previously installed. CUDA® itself would require a set of specific GPU drivers. On Linux, you can install by `pip install qiskit-aer-gpu`, on other platforms you need to build the package from source.

Note that `qiskit-aer` and `qiskit-aer-gpu` are mutually exclusive. They contain the same code but the latter supports CUDA. If you install both at the same it will interfere with each other. See [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14409/7474) for more details.

Furthermore, you can use `cusvaer` or `cuStateVec` from NVIDIA’s cuQuantum SDK (requires CUDA as well) with Qiskit to utilize GPU for simulation. See some code examples [here](https://medium.com/qiskit/improve-quantum-simulations-with-qiskit-aer-cuquantum-9cd4bf69f042) and the [cuQuantum documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuquantum/appliance/qiskit.html).

Comment: [This page](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-aer-gpu/) states:

"If you want to install our GPU supported simulators, you have to install this other package:

`pip install qiskit-aer-gpu`

This will overwrite your current `qiskit-aer` package installation giving you the same functionality found in the canonical `qiskit-aer` package, plus the ability to run the GPU supported simulators: statevector, density matrix, and unitary."

If this information is correct (no need to uninstall `qiskit-aer` anymore), can you update your answer to reflect so please?

Comment: I am not sure it’s needed to uninstall qiskit-aer and I can’t test I because I don’t have a machine with NVIDIA GPU…

Comment: No problem, I'll try to test it and will tell you the result. Don't hesitate to ping me if I forget to do so in several days, I think this question could be useful to a large number of people, so it might be worth the effort!

Comment: That would be great. Thanks a lot!